# ExceptionMapper and code coverage in Sonar

Tags: java, rest, code-coverage, sonarqube

My REST service uses `ExceptionMapper`s to nicely translate exceptions that occur while processing requests to responses that are sent to the client.

The code generally looks like this:

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MyException exception) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Problem is, Sonar reports all the code in this class as "uncovered" by the code coverage checks, even though the mapper is instantiated during integration tests and these tests show that the class is actually used and the mapper executed.

Is it possible to let Sonar cover this kind of code?

Comment: What is the version of the java plugin you are using and what coverage tool are you using ? (JaCoCo, Cobertura ?). SonarQube and Java plugin are just exploiting the coverage reports generated by those tools.

Comment: Coverage is from JaCoCo. SonarQube is 3.7.x and I believe the Java plugin came packaged with Sonar.